# Find email address of Twitter user

Tags: twitter

My main objective to send direct message to a Twitter user. However I realized that I cannot do that until that user follows me.

So is there any way to get the email id of that Twitter user so that I can send email?

Or else is there any way to send direct message even that user is not following me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, It's part of the deal that they are not sharing your e-mail with the rest of the world.

[image: privacy setting]

Answer (score 4):

You can't direct message the other user, but you can send a public message that will come to the attention of the user simply by starting a tweet with @*username*.

Every Twitter client I've tried has a way of alerting mentions like this.

This is as good as you're going to get.